# Can I specify the type of a function at definition from a Protocol?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, typing

In a project, I define a function type using Protocols from the typing module but the functions matching that Protocol are scattered in different files. I would like to indicate that a particular function matches the Protocol (to find them more easily) but I cannot find how.

For example, here I would like to indicate that `f` is an `FType` :

```py
from typing import Protocol

class FType(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, a: int) -> float: ...


def f(a: int) -> float:
    return float(a)
```

I tried the following :

```py
from typing import Protocol

class FType(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, a: int) -> float: ...


def f(a: int) -> float:
    return float(a)


def g(a: int) -> str:
    return str(a)
   

f: FType = f  # OK
g: FType = g  # not OK
```

This allows me to find the functions matching `FType` in my editor but I don't like the repetition and `g: FType = g` is not detected as an error by mypy.

Is there a better way of doing so ?

Something like this would be nice :

```py
:FType
def f(a: int) -> float:
    return float(a)
```

Comment: There's no point using `FType` as a type annotation for the functions, since the type checker already understands that `f` implements the `FType` interface and `g` doesn't. Think about it, who are you trying to communicate with? Not the type checker, but rather the programmer. So how do programmers communicate with each other? By writing comments. Just add a `# implements FType` or something like that to the function definition.

Comment: the issue with that is that my editor (pycharm) wouldn't know that `f` implements FType, meaning that I cannot `crtl+b` to find functions matching `FType`, but myabe it is more of a feature request for pycharm

Comment: If you  **really** need this, you can write a no-op decorator with signature like `as_ftype(func: FType) -> FType`. Also, is the variable name important for you? Otherwise `Callable` would be better fit, or `def __call__(self, __a: int) -> float:` - var name starting with double underscore.